# JQuery append a div start tag only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to insert only a div start tag like `$('#adiv').append("<div class='divtoinsert>'");`

but it creates: `<div class='divtoinsert></div>` instead.

I want it to append only the start tag because in the middle, I am adding some content and I want it to insert an end tag when I have added all the content.

I am looking over the net a day now but unlucky enough to give me a hint.

Comment: You can store created html in variable and at end append it to document.

Comment: Why don't you append the content on the new tag ?

Comment: in such case create a just unattached DOM element var like `var myDiv = $('<div></div>')`. Append all the contents to this and finally insert into DOM structure.

Comment: You have to understand that `$('#adiv').append("<div class='divtoinsert'>")` does *not* generate any HTML. It merely adds a node to the DOM tree which can be amended as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just create a string variable to hold the open tag, concatenate your content to it inside a loop or whatever you want, then concatenate the closing tag. You can then append the variable to your element when finished.

Example:

```
var yourText = "<div>";

yourText += //whatever you want

yourText += "</div>";

$('#adiv').append(yourText);
```

Comment: yah this is the best way.cheers

Comment: Thanks @Drew Kennedy. It works

Answer (score 1):

You should first build the content object and then append it to the element you want. For example:

```
function addColorObject(color){
    var obj = '<div style="background-color:'+color+';">Hello!</div>';
    $('#adiv').append(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First store the current html of body tag as a string and append the start tag of your div and then set the body html

```
 $(function(){
      var newbody =$("body").html()+" <div id='foo'>";
       $("body").html(newBody);

      console.log(newbody);
    });
```